# Array not changing after sorting function call

Tags: c++, sorting

When sorting an vector using an implementation of insertion sort, the array I passed as an argument doesn't change as a result.

I've tried this before and can't find my issue, some help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void insertionSort(vector<int> arr);
int main() {
    vector<int> vec;
    const int arrSize = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        vec.push_back(rand() % 10); // 3 6 7 5 3
    }
    for (auto i : vec) cout << i << endl; // 3 6 7 5 3
    insertionSort(vec);
    for (auto i : vec) cout << i << endl; // 3 6 7 5 3
}

void insertionSort(vector<int> arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) {
        int j = i + 1;
        while(j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
            swap(arr[j - 1], arr[j]);
            j--;
        }
    }
    for (auto i : vec) cout << i << endl; // 3 3 5 6 7
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Arguments are copied by value unless a reference is passed. To modify the object you pass in, use a reference instead.

Pass a `vector<int> &arr` instead of a mere `vector<int> arr`. Note the `&`.

Another way, would be to return the sorted array and assign it to your old, unsorted array.

---

Some tips:

1. Prior to `rand`, call `srand` to initialize the PRNG with a seed. Since C++11, there is also `<random>`, which you should favor anyway.
2. `std::endl` flushes the stream buffer. `'\n'` does not, but has the same visual effect. Favor `'\n'` unless you actually want to flush the stream buffer. Especially in loops, where repeated flushing is superfluous and inefficient.
3. Use the appropriate size type for STL data structures. For `std::vector`, this is `std::vector<T>::size_type` a.k.a. `std::size_t`. The same as for arrays, BTW. Instead of `int`, use `std::size_t`. `std::vector::size` also returns a `std::size_t`, not an `int`.